# C# で ToString() と Parse() の仕組みの違い

Tags: c#

なぜ `Parse(変換したい文字)` と同じように `ToString(変換したい数値)` ではなくて
`(変換したい数値).ToString()` という形で「引数でデータを受け取らないのに」変換できているのですか？

変換するメソッドの場合は次のコードのようなら理解できるのですが

```
public string ToString(int i)
{   
    処理;
    return str;
}
```

調べても定義を見てもわからなかったので、自分で変換メソッド定義して理解しようとしたのですがクラスのコンストラクタの引数に変換したい数値を渡して `ToString()` で使用するぐらいしか思いつきませんでした。ですが実際は `(変換したい数値).ToString()` の一文のみでそういったやりとりをしていません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の Microsoft ドキュメントは参考になりませんか？

Object クラス
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-7.0

Object.ToString メソッド
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-7.0

関係するところを抜粋すると:

Object クラスは、.NET の全クラスの基本クラスであり、型階層のルートです。

.NET では、すべてのクラスが Object から派生するため、システム内のオブジェクトは、Object クラスで定義されているすべてのメソッドを使用できます。派生クラスでは、これらのメソッドのうち、次のメソッドをオーバーライドできます。

・ToString - クラスのインスタンスの説明テキスト文字列をユーザーが判読できる形で生成します。

実装元へのメモ:
型に対して有効な値を返すようにするため、派生クラスでこのメソッドをオーバーライドできます。たとえば Int32 などの基本データ型は、オブジェクトが表す値を文字列として返すために ToString を実装します。

ということで、質問の、

> なぜ Parse(変換したい文字) と同じように ToString(変換したい数値) ではなくて(変換したい数値).ToString() という形で「引数でデータを受け取らないのに」変換できているのですか？

に対する答えは、そういう実装になっているからということになります。

なお、Int32 の場合は「(変換したい数値).ToString()」だけではなくて、以下の画像のようなオーバーロードがあります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 型をよく理解していなかったみたいです。型intはInt32構造体のエイリアスで、当然Objectクラスから派生していてToString()を持っているから(int).ToString()がOK。intのような変数とクラスを完全に別物として考えていたため[変数.ToString()]はおかしいと感じていたようです。